# jqGrid get cell data into delOptions property

Tags: javascript, jqgrid

I have a colModel column that when a user presses the button, it will delete the row. However, I need this to go to the server (which is does) and delete it from the database using the row's ID.

This is the code that does it

```
      colModel: [
           ...

            { name: 'id', index: 'Id', width: 70, hidden: true, editable: true, 
            {
                name: 'actions', index: 'actions', width: 20, sortable: false, editable: false, formatter: imageFormat,
                formatoptions: {
                    keys: true,
                    editbutton: false,
     // I need to pass id from above into the server....this is what should happen here
                    delOptions: { url: Controller + 'Action?paramenter=' + id}
                }
            },

        ],
```

The problem is that I need to get the value of the id column and pass it in the parameter like above.

How can this be done?

Thanks

Comment: Delete use HTTP POST to send the id of deleted row. Do you want to change HTTP POST to HTTP GET for deleting? See [the documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing#what_is_posted_to_the_server2)

Comment: Hi @Oleg  - Why would a GET be better than a POST for deleting? As I am posting data to the server, i.e. an id

Comment: It seems that you don't understand my question. In case of usage HTTP POST the id of the deleted row will be placed in the *body* of the Delete request. The body will be like `oper=del&id=123`. What you ask is to use `?paramenter=' + id` in the URL. It corresponds to placing parameters in URL in HTTP GET request. Would be enough if the information which you need will be send in the body of the Delete request?

Comment: Oh I see, so using HTTPGet, I would got the id for free kind of thing?

Comment: If you would use `delOptions: { url: Controller + "Action", mtype : "GET" }` then the URL used by jqGrid will be `Controller + "Action?id" + rowid + "&oper=del"`. Is it what you need of you need to have other information as the id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I didnt use `delOptions` I used the `.jqGrid('delGridRow')` method inside the `onSelectRow` property,

and to get the id I used..

```
var myGrid = $('#grid'),
selRowId = myGrid.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow'),
celValue = myGrid.jqGrid('getCell', selRowId, 'name');
```

So therefore...

```
 jQuery("#resume").jqGrid('delGridRow', id, { height: 480, width: 400, closeAfterAdd: true, closeAfterEdit: true, recreateForm: true,url: Controller + 'Action?paramenter=' + celValue });
```

Comment: If you fill the grid correctly you should have the same values for `selRowId` and `celValue`. If it's not so, then you should include one row of input data which you use to fill jqGrid and `datatype` which you use. I would show you how to fix the problem.

Comment: You used `name: 'id', index: 'Id'` which is suspected. Probably the name of `id` is `Id` in the source data?

Comment: It was an example of a field, I will rename it to something else

Comment: So you need to send the value of some other column as rowid during Delete? Do you want to get the information from URL or from POSTed data like `oper=del&id=123&paramenter=myData`?

Answer (score 0):

with the loadComplete() method, you can do like this:

```
$(table).find(".ui-inline-del").each(function() {
var delDivBtn = $(this);
var id_reg = /(\w+)([_]{1})(\w+$)/;

// remove the delete event
$(delDivBtn).removeAttr("onclick");

// add new click event 
$(delDivBtn).click(function() {
    var rowid = delDivBtn.attr("id").replace(id_reg, '$3');
    alert(rowid);
});
```

});